# Python: How to create 2D array using existing lists

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have been trying to resolve this issue.

I have 3 lists

```
dev = ['Alex', 'Ashley', 'Colin']
phone = ['iPhone', 'Nexus', 'Nokia']
carrier = ['ATT', 'T-Mobile', 'MegaFon']
```

Is this a pythonic way to create a new 2D array like this:

```
matrix = [['Alex', 'iPhone', 'ATT'], ['Ashley','Nexus','T-Mobile'], ['Colin', 'Nokia', 'MegaFon']]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
>>> zip(dev, phone, carrier)
[('Alex', 'iPhone', 'ATT'),
 ('Ashley', 'Nexus', 'T-Mobile'),
 ('Colin', 'Nokia', 'MegaFon')]
```

See [`zip` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip).

If you need a list of lists (instead of a list of tuples in Python 2, or an iterator in Python 3), use Padraic's suggestion: `[list(x) for x in zip(dev, phone, carrier)]`.

Comment: `[list(x) for x in zip(dev,phone,carrier)]` to get a lists of lists

Comment: Thanks @PadraicCunningham.  Your method also works as requested for Python 3 (where `zip` returns an iterator).  Updated my answer.